# Turning off .hover() if window size changes

Tags: jquery

I would like to turn off a jQuery `.hover()` function if the window size changes to less than `300px`. I wrote this code:

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 300) {
    $(".link").hover(function() {
      $(this).text("Alternative Text");
    }, function() {
      $(this).text("Hover me");
    });
  } else {
    $('.link').off("hover");
  }
}).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="link">Hover me</div>
```

If I change my window size to less than `300px` and then reload the page, it works perfectly like expected. The `else` function is not even needed in this case. But if the window size gets manually changed by the user to less to `300px`, the hover function just stays.

How can the hover function be removed for window sizes under `300px`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `hover` is an hybrid event, I don't think it can be revoked.
Here's a workaround: use a global variable (or check `$(window).width()` every hover).

```js
var is_desktop = $(window).width() > 300;
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 300) {
    is_desktop = true
  } else {
    is_desktop = false
  }
})


$(".link").hover(function() {
  if (is_desktop) {
    $(this).text("Alternative Text");
  }
}, function() {
  if (is_desktop) {
    $(this).text("Hover me");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="link">Hover me</div>
```

If you do want to remove the handlers, then define `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` using 2 functions that can then be referenced in the `off` for those events.

Comment: Thank you! But with that, it only works on resize but not on load?